# In SSRS what does the option 'Log in using these credentials, but then try to impersonate the user viewing the report' do?

Tags: ssrs-2008

When I add a new Data source via the web browser, there is the following option: *'Log in using these credentials, but then try to impersonate the user viewing the report'*?

What does this option do?
What are the advantages?

I tried and read the docs but I still don't understand it.
This is with latest version of SQL reporting service.

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no answer yet I will explain what a colleague of mine told me in short.
It basically comes down that you login with an order account it's privilege's.
So in the meantime I am not using it as I don't see the advantage of it and only complicates things.